# RequireJS: Module missing dependency after optimization

Tags: javascript, requirejs, grunt-contrib-requirejs

After a long development, I decided it was time to ship an optimized/bundled version of the JS in our project. So having used requirejs since the beginning, I thought it would be as simple as doing `grunt build`. Evidently, I was wrong and I spent a long time fixing missing dependencies in every module. But now I cannot solve 1 issue and I feel like I have tried everything.

I have module `models/User.js` like that:

```
define(["oauthio", ...], function (oauthIO, ...) {
})
```

and it worked well until the optimization. Now my app crashes with a cryptic `Uncaught Error: models/User missing oauthio`. I tried to force the inclusion of `oauthio` with the `include` option passed to r.js (I am using grunt-contrib-requirejs) but to no avail...

What else can I try ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is oauthio named module? Do you have path to the module set inside require.config?

Comment: `oauthio` is not a named module, the path is set in require.config: `'../libs/oauth.io'`

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing everything, shouldn't oauthio have js extenstion?